# Python User Input Checkerboard

Tags: python, input, turtle-graphics

For my assignment, I'm trying to make a 5 x 5 checkerboard with the user choice in color and square size. I got how to make square sizes and colors based on the user input and am having some trouble with how to start a loop or how to create a 5 x 5 checkerboard. I'm just not sure what I could do to move the turtle to make a 5x5 board. I have this much done so far, if anyone could help me get started, i would really appreciate it!

```
import turtle

def main():
    length = int(input("Enter a desired length (from 1-150.)"))
    keepGoing = 'y'

    while keepGoing == 'y':
        print("What color would you like to draw?")
        print("    Enter 1 for Black")
        print("          2 for Blue")
        print("          3 for Red")
        print("          4 for Green")
        choice = int(input("          Your choice?"))

        if choice == 1:
            square(0,0,length,'black')
        elif choice == 2:
            square(0,0,length,'blue')
        elif choice == 3:
            square(0,0,length,'red')
        elif choice == 4:
            square(0,0,length,'green')
        else:
            print("ERROR: only enter 1-4.")

def square(x, y, width, color):
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.penup()            # Raise the pen
    turtle.goto(x, y)         # Move to (X,Y)
    turtle.fillcolor(color)   # Set the fill color
    turtle.pendown()          # Lower the pen
    turtle.begin_fill()       # Start filling
    for count in range(4):    # Draw a square
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
#calling main function
main()
```

Comment: Just draw and fill each square.  Loop over all the squares, determining their position.  Then draw an appropriately-colored square at each position.

Answer (score 0):

First, you developed your user interface without having anything to interface to -- you might start the other way around next time.  Second, don't reinvent booleans (e.g. `while keepGoing == 'y'`).  Third, for the amount of code it took you to ***draw*** one square, we can ***stamp*** the entire grid:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

COLORS = ["Black", "Blue", "Red", "Green"]
GRID = 5
STAMP_UNIT = 20

def main():
    length = int(input("Enter a desired length (from 1-150): "))
    keepGoing = True

    while keepGoing:
        print("What color would you like to draw?")
        for i, color in enumerate(COLORS, start=1):
            print("    Enter {} for {}".format(i, color))
        choice = int(input("          Your choice? "))

        if 1 <= choice <= len(COLORS):
            grid(-length * GRID // 2, -length * GRID // 2, length, COLORS[choice - 1])
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            print("ERROR: only enter 1-{}.".format(len(COLORS)))

def grid(x, y, width, color):
    tortoise = Turtle('square', visible=False)
    tortoise.shapesize(width / STAMP_UNIT)
    tortoise.color(color)
    tortoise.penup()

    for dy in range(0, GRID):
        tortoise.goto(x, y + width * dy)

        for dx in range(dy % 2, GRID, 2):
            tortoise.setx(x + width * dx)

            tortoise.stamp()

screen = Screen()

main()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**USAGE**

```
> python3 test.py
Enter a desired length (from 1-150): 30
What color would you like to draw?
    Enter 1 for Black
    Enter 2 for Blue
    Enter 3 for Red
    Enter 4 for Green
          Your choice? 2
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

This is a perfect example of where stamping can make things simpler and faster than drawing.